# rest template logging request and response for specific endpoint only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, resttemplate

Im trying to get log the Rest template request and response and it **working** and my reference is this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-logging and https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-resttemplate-request-response-logging-f021be66c2c0
but the problem is, its getting it **all endpont**. I want for a c**ertain endpoint only**. https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template .If you have suggestion, kindly share.I been looking for a solution for days.

Comment: Create 2 `RestTemplate` instances, one with and the other without the logging. Use the logging one wherever you want to use logging. You can use an `@Qualifier` for that (create one yourself and use that on the bean and target, like `@Logged`), define the one used by default as `@Primary`).

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can think of this:

1. Implement the URLs (or patterns) you want to log in your interceptor
2. Configure 2 `RestTemplate` instances one with and one without logging and decide which to use where. You can use a dedicated `@Qualifier` for this.

```java
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,
            ElementType.METHOD,
            ElementType.TYPE,
            ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Logged {}
```

You can now use this qualifing annotation to create 2 beans and put it on the `@Autowired` field or constructor argument to decide which to inject.

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder rtb) {
  return rtb.build();
}

@Bean
@Logged
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder rtb) {
  return rtb.interceptors(new RequestLoggingInterceptor()).build();
}
```

Now your code will use the `@Primary` one where ever there is a `RestTemplate` needed. If you want to use the logging one then explicitly annotate that place with `@Logged`.

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

  private final RestTemplate rest;

  public MyService(@Logged RestTemplate rest) {
    this.rest=rest;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i tried the URL  pattern but it only work for controller side and for the solution 2 Im hoping it will work but it still getting it all, and btw i used RestTemplateCustomizer

Comment: I have no idea what you tried... The URL pattern would be applied in your custom interceptor. You haven't used solution to you tried your own, the `RestTEmplateCustomizer` will be applied to all `RestTemplate` instances. I didn't give you the code and solution for you to do something completly else?